# Backwards Compatible COM Referencing in .NET

Tags: c#, com

As a simple example, I'm wanting to use CertEnroll to get a certificate in .NET.  A single line of code that shows the failure:

```
CX509CertificateRequestPkcs10 certRequest = new CX509CertificateRequestPkcs10();
```

My dev box is Windows 10, and when I compile and run the code there it works fine.  However compiling on Win10 and copying the binaries to an 'older' OS (Windows Server 2008 R2 for example) it throws an InvalidCastException saying No such interface supported.

From my understanding this stems from the fact that Windows 10's com file of CertEnroll is newer.  Looking at the Interop for CX509CertificateRequestPkcs10, it implements IX509CertificateRequestPkcs10V5 but on Server it's only IX509CertificateRequestPkcs10V5.  So when compiling on Windows 10 the generated interop expects the runtime object to implement an interface that the Windows Server COM implementation doesn't know about.

From my research I've discovered the following possible solutions, though I'm uncertain which is the "correct" way to do it.

1) Continue using COMReference and only build on the lowest operating system we support (unacceptable for developer purposes)

2) Grab the CertEnroll dll from the lowest operating system and reference it using a COMFileReference.  (This seems wrong because then we're hard coding against that binary instead of using the more up to date CertEnroll on newer operating systems)

3) Grab CertEnroll from the lowest operating system, us it to generate a tlb file and reference that using a COMFileReference.  I thought this would work since the tlb would be the more 'restrictive' due to it coming from the lowest operating system, but it seems when Visual Studio generates the actual Interop binary it still uses my Windows 10 CertEnroll interfaces making it incompatible with the lower operating systems.

4) Grab CertEnroll from the lowest operating system, us it to generate a tlb file as well as the Interop file, both manually.  Reference the Interop as a COMFileReference.  Here I'm not sure how this would work, would I need to run tlbimp on Server 2008 as well to make sure the Interop is generated using the older version of the COM reference?

If I'm missing something completely and there's another option around this, please let me know.

Comment: When I decompile the type library with OleView.exe on my machine (Win10 1607) it tells me that the default interface is IX509CertificateRequestPkcs10V4.  How you got V5 is hard to guess.  Typical agile bug btw, a big Win10 problem.  Cast to IX509CertificateRequestPkcs10V3 to keep it backwards compatible.